# PHP String to Array

Tags: php, массивы, строки

подскажите правильное решение по переводу строки в массив .Есть метод класса который возвращает ответ в виде массива `

```
[
       [[ ],[ ],[ ],[ ],[ ],[1],[2]],
       [[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9]],
       [[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16]],
       [[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23]],
       [[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30]]
       ]
```

`
Но ответ возвращается в string. Как перевести его в array?
Класс переделывать не желательно но если нужно то опишите  пожалуйста вкратце почему.

Comment: echo is_array($arr) ? 'Массив' : 'Не массив';

Comment: var_dump($arr) string

Comment: если строка, то в таком виде, значит где то  косяк кода который так возвращает

Comment: $str='"a"=>"text","b"=>"text2"';
$arr=array("a"=>"text","b"=>"text2"); 
$arr=eval('return ['.$str.'];'); Но это частный случай

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Есть метод класса который возвращает ответ в виде массива

Если метод класса возвращает массив, то он должна возвращать массив. А не строку.

Но вообще можно использовать json_decode()

Comment: при условии что это можно рассматривать как сериализованный в json массив, то пассаж не понятен. Возможно данный код написан не автором, а целей его написания автор не понимает.